# android compile meet app:dexDebug OOM

Tags: android

I meet a issue is app:dexDebug and  multiDexEnabled already set true
but still OOM..
pure android studio, any idea to solve it? thanks

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.

  > com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
  >       /Volumes/programfile/Android_MAC/android-sdk-macosx/build-tools/22.0.1/dx --dex --no-optimize --multi-dex --main-dex-list /Users/Ymow/project/android/app/build/intermediates/multi-dex/debug/maindexlist.txt --output /Users/Ymow/project/android/app/build/intermediates/dex/debug --input-list=/Users/Ymow/project/android/app/build/intermediates/tmp/dex/debug/inputList.txt
  >     Error Code:
  >       3
  >     Output:

  ```
  UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL ERROR:
  java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
      at com.android.dx.rop.code.RopMethod.calcPredecessors(RopMethod.java:173)
      at com.android.dx.rop.code.RopMethod.labelToPredecessors(RopMethod.java:94)
      at com.android.dx.dex.code.RopTranslator.pickOrder(RopTranslator.java:351)
      at com.android.dx.dex.code.RopTranslator.translateAndGetResult(RopTranslator.java:211)
      at com.android.dx.dex.code.RopTranslator.translate(RopTranslator.java:105)
      at com.android.dx.dex.cf.CfTranslator.processMethods(CfTranslator.java:317)
      at com.android.dx.dex.cf.CfTranslator.translate0(CfTranslator.java:137)
      at com.android.dx.dex.cf.CfTranslator.translate(CfTranslator.java:93)
      at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:729)
      at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:673)
      at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$300(Main.java:83)
      at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$1.processFileBytes(Main.java:602)
      at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:284)
      at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:166)
      at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
      at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:632)
      at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:505)
      at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMultiDex(Main.java:334)
      at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:244)
      at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
      at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
  ```

  - Try:
    Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

  BUILD FAILED

  Total time: 3 mins 40.988 secs

Comment: it would seem that you exceeded the 65k functions limit

Comment: Are you using AS or eclipse?

Comment: @tofiffe yes, I figure out after this post..
@ Sanjeet AS and not import from eclipse

Comment: but i found method_ids_size     : 62586
is under 65k

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?

```
dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "2g"
}
```

Comment: yes, one of that, I change to 4g and set multiple dex, it's fine, thanks reply